# Complex Numbers Graphing Argand Diagram

Tags: complex-numbers

Graph this on the Argand Diagram:

$|z+1| \lt |z-1|$

Firstly I assumed that you square each side to remove the absolute value, getting:

$4z+2 \gt 0 $

However, that method seems to get me nowhere.
Then, I made $z= x+iy$ - But not sure where that gets me. Can someone please assist me because it's probably something really simple, that I can't solve.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at $|z+1|=|z-(-1)|$ as the distance from $z$ to $-1$, and similarly for $|z-1|$. Then you're looking for the set of points whose distance to $1$ is greater than the distance to $-1$.